# Can we configure spring cloud gateway and service discovery (eureka server) on same SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to run Spring Cloud "Gateway" & "Eureka-Server" on the same @SpringBootApplication, below is my code :

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableAdminServer
public class DemoGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoGatewayApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${GATEWAY_SERVER_PORT:8080}
             
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    appname: ${spring.application.name}
  client:
    enabled: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 10
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 10
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${REGISTRY_SERVER_IP:localhost}:${REGISTRY_SERVER_PORT:8080}/eureka
```

When I run this application I am getting errors as below. I am not sure what is the issue or is it possible to have a gateway and eureka server on the same instance?

```
2021-09-13 18:10:12.411  INFO [gateway-service,,] 224 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAY-SERVICE/gateway-service:9fd20bce350b1ccb477d53ad05e3504f - registration status: 404
2021-09-13 18:10:12.831  INFO [gateway-service,,] 224 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2021-09-13 18:10:13.979  INFO [gateway-service,,] 224 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2021-09-13 18:10:14.056  INFO [gateway-service,,] 224 --- [           main] c.n.gateway.DemoGatewayApplication    : Started DemoGatewayApplication in 27.56 seconds (JVM running for 29.713)
2021-09-13 18:10:15.459  INFO [gateway-service,,] 224 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8080/eureka/}
```

Comment: I'd say no. Eureka server doesn't play well with others. I've not seen it since successfully. The spring cloud team recommends running eureka server independently. It really should have multiple nodes for redundancy

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for your answer. I have made the changes accordingly.